# how can i install dash boostrap components

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- dash-boostrap-components

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

conda install dash-boostrap-components

Got this error while trying to install dash_boostrap_components

Any help please

Comment: You're missing the error text

Comment: Installed successfully, thanks